# degree of $P(x)$ , the minimal polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ be a $10 \times 10$ matrix defined by $A=(a_{ij})$ where $(a_{ij})=1-(-1)^{i-j}$. If $P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ then

1) degree of $P(x)$?

2) coefficient of $x$ in $P(x)$?

My work:
 First of all I find the matrix it is of the form 
   \begin{pmatrix} 
     0 & 2 & 0 & 2\:\cdots&0 &2 \\ 
     2 & 0 & 2 & 0\:\cdots&2 &0 \\
     \vdots &\vdots &\vdots & &\vdots &\vdots\\
      0 & 2 & 0 & 2\:\cdots&0 &2\\
      2 & 0 & 2 & 0\:\cdots&2 &0\\ 
   \end{pmatrix}

and I find $10$ is an eigen value with geometric multiplicity one and I also find solution of $Ax=0$ and see that geometric multiplicity is $8$ corresponding to the eigenvalue zero. From that I can say the matrix has zero as an eigenvalue at least  $8$. But How do I find another eigenvalue or is there anything wrong?
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your results are correct, always remind that if your matrix is $A$
$$
\text{Trace}\left(A\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lambda_k
$$
where $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ counted with multiplicity. Here you have
$$
\text{Trace}\left(A\right)=10+\lambda=0
$$

Comment: Can u do little favor, what is the other way to check the minimal polynomial other than the usual way for large matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let me define the vectors
$$
v_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0\\\vdots}, \quad 
v_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\1\\\vdots}.
$$
Then
$$
Av_1 = 10 v_2, \ Av_2 = 10 v_1,
$$
which implies
$$
A^2v_1 = 100 v_1, \ A^2 v_2 = 100 v_2.
$$
If $x$ is orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$ then $Ax=0$.
Since the columns of $A$ are multiples of $v_1,v_2$, we have
$$ 
(A^2- 100 I)A = (A-10I)(A+10I)A=0.
$$

Comment: It should be "If $x$ is orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$ then $Ax=0$."

Comment: @YadatiKiran of course! Thanks